# Angular: ERROR in Symbol CommonModule ... is not exported from @angular/common

Tags: angular

I have a submodule in my project, and after installing the packages and trying to use the npm start i get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZd8L.png)

The commands i did in order where the same my co-worker did, except it worked fine for him

1 - git clone X

2 - git submodule init

3 - git submodule update --remote

4 - npm install

5 - ng serve

Can anyone help me? I did not find any related issue like this.